# code takes longer time then expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ios

My code takes longer time then expected. How can I reduce loading time? Previously it was no taking this much time. I havent changed the code and yet it has slowed down.
My code flows as below:

```
for (i =1 ; i< [productList count]; i++) {
    UIImage *image;
    products *productItem = [productList objectAtIndex:i-1];
    if(![productItem.productItemPhoto isEqualToString:@""]){
        NSString *productItemPhoto = productItem.productItemPhoto;          
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:productItemPhoto];
        image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    }
    else{
        if(numberOfProductsPerRow == 1)
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image-2.png"];
        else
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image-1.png"];
    }
    UIImageView *bg1;
    if(numberOfProductsPerRow == 1)
        bg1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-box-s7.png"]];
    else            
        bg1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-box-s4.png"]];
        bg1.frame = CGRectMake(x, y,width, height);
        [productScrollView addSubview:bg1];

        UIButton *pro1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+spacingX, y+spacingY-15, btnWidth, btnHeight)];

    [pro1 setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [pro1 setTag:i];
        [pro1 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectProduct:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [productScrollView addSubview:pro1 ];

        UILabel *lblProductModel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, height - 40, width, 30)];
        lblProductModel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblProductModel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lblProductModel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.8 blue:0.0 alpha:1];
        NSString *price;

        if([userSettings.priceToShow isEqualToString:@"WholesalePrice"])
            price = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%.0f",productItem.productCurrencySymbol, productItem.productWholesalePrice];
        else if([userSettings.priceToShow isEqualToString:@"RetailsalePrice"])
            price = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%.0f",productItem.productCurrencySymbol, productItem.productRetailSalesValue];
        else
            price = @"";
        lblProductModel.tag = [productList count] + i;
        lblProductModel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", productItem.productModelCode,  price];
        [bg1 addSubview:lblProductModel];
        x = x + width + 10;
        if(i%numberOfProductsPerRow == 0){
            x = 20;
            y=y+height+10;
        }
        [pro1 release];
        [image release];
        [bg1 release];
        [lblProductModel release];

}
if((i-1)%numberOfProductsPerRow!=0)
    scrollViewParent.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, y+height+spacingY);
else    
    scrollViewParent.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, y + spacingY);
productScrollView.contentSize = scrollViewParent.contentSize;
[scrollViewParent addSubview:productScrollView];
}
```

Some 380 records are coming in productList. I dont think that it should take this much time.

Comment: How much time is it taking? How much time are you expecting it to take? And how are you measuring how long it takes?

Comment: It is taking 2 to 3 seconds. It should be within fraction of second.

Comment: You should do such long processing on a separate thread.

Comment: If you have not changed the code then it must be the test data that have changed, e.g. larger images, etc. If all 380 records contains images, then 2-3 seconds are really not that long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the amount of futzing with `UI*` API in that code, that code must be running on the main thread.   You are loading a ton of images on the main thread and image loading is a very slow & expensive operation, comparatively speaking.

First, do you really need to load all 380 images at the start?  What happens when that grows to 500 or 1,500 or 15,000?   I'd bet your app runs out of memory somewhere between 380 and 15,000....

Your code should only load the images it needs and, then, do so outside of that loop.  Anything that runs on the main thread will block user interaction for as long as it runs;   keeping those periods of time as short as possible (or, ideally, not at all by moving the computation to a background queue/thread) is ideal.

Comment: I loaded images first screen i.e 8 images at a time and remaining images are loaded when the user scrolls down. Now the code works fine.

Comment: Awesome;  that sounds like a much more scalable design, too!   At some point, you'll want to think about unloading previously loaded images to ensure that you don't blow out memory (if the # of images grows).

Comment: In addition to that I am implementing pagination i.e 100 images at a time. The size of images led to memory leak. So found a solution this way... :)